# SVG.DLL Bitmap to unmanaged code

Tags: svg

I have acquired the .NET SVG.DLL and written a test harness to see if this DLL will solve an SVG problem I have, and in fact it has. Now ... for this BIG hurdle, I need to marshall or return the Bitmap, Image, or what ever is easiest method back to the main C++ code that needs the Bitmap.

Can anyone please help.

Al Harper

Answer (score 0):

Well I seemed have have finally figure out how to get bitmap from managed to unmanaged cpp code. In short I used the HBITMAP handle retrieved in the managed code, then re hydrated a bitmap in the CPP code from it.

Let me know if anyone wants a code snippet.

Al Harper